# How to make phonegap window.location.href not launch Chrome on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I've got a phonegap app. On deviceReady I set `window.location.href` to some other URL. This works great on iOS 8.3 but on Android 5.0.1 I get asked if I want to open it in Chrome and then it's opened in Chrome instead of my app.

Is there way to get the URL to open in the app (as in replace the current page). Yes I know that's not *best practice*, a one page app is better, blah blah blah but that doesn't fit my use case at the moment.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using cordova 5 (or above) with the android platform 4.0.0 (or above), have a look at: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

install the plugin via:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git --save`

in your config.xml you need to add:

`<allow-navigation href="https://example.com/*" />`

thanks to that, you will allow the webview to load your page.

Comment: This is absolutedly correct and fixed the issue for me. Not sure why its not marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Dbaq's answer is very valid. But I found another scenario where this still does not work (and you might get the webView popup): The URL needs to be well formed (i.e. if you are specifying a folder, make sure that you type the ending slash: 'https://example.com/folder' will give you the popup while 'https://example.com/folder/' works just fine)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.location=url;
```

if this doesn't work, install [inAppBrowser plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) and use this

```
window.open(url,"_self");
```

and of course inside device ready function.

Comment: this is not working, he is asking how to replace the index.html. not to use the inappbrowser.

Comment: And just by guessing you've given a down vote!! Don't you think it would be wise him to decide what he wanted actually! Anyway there is nothing wrong to use inApp @dbaq

Comment: I am not guessing anything, he said : ```Is there way to get the URL to open in the app (as in replace the current page)```

he wants to replace the current page, not open in a browser (inapp or system)